# Sprite Kit app crashes when run on real device and plugged into computer

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, ios10, xcode8

I just updated to iOS 10 on my test phone and Xcode 8. I ran the code migration and was running tests successfully on my simulated devices.

However, once I started trying to test on my real device things stopped working smoothly. After running my Sprite Kit game for around 5 - 10 seconds it would crash and render the phone inoperable until I unplugged it from the computer. After I unplug it the game runs as normal and is still really smooth.

This are the startup notifications printed to the console:

```
2016-09-15 22:20:49.490959 AppName[411:38688] [DYMTLInitPlatform] platform initialization successful
2016-09-15 22:20:49.684189 AppName[411:38634] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled
2016-09-15 22:20:49.684758 AppName[411:38634] Metal API Validation Enabled
```

This is the error I receive after the app crashes when the phone is plugged in:

```
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Metal/Metal-85.83/ToolsLayers/Debug/MTLDebugRenderCommandEncoder.mm:130: failed assertion `indexBufferOffset(12) + (indexCount(480) * 2) must be <= [indexBuffer length](960).'
(lldb)
```

Comment: did you do a clean build

Comment: you are going beyond your buffer (I am assuming you are not accessing metal correctly, sprite kit is doing it)

Answer (score 1):

try to disable Metal verification by editing the scheme:

1. (Command-Option-R)
2. go to the Options tab.
3. Set Metal API Validation to Disabled.

This worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

I can resolve this, unchecking "Debug executable" in the Scheme
[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Command-Option-R
- "Wait for executable to be launched"
- manual run

works for me from time to time.